# How to add elements to array of blocked tasks while performing another task

Tags: java

I am making a simple multithreaded program, I have an array of strings representing the tasks. whenever I press on a button a string representing the task is created and added to the array and when I release the button the task that that has the turn is executed. However, For some reason the array always contains one element.
For example whenever I execute task close() and before it finishes execution I click on accelerate, Accelerate gets executed as soon as Close() is done but doesn't get added to the array until close() has finished execution.

```
// Add Accelerate Task To Array
btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (!running) {
                    label_1.setText("Click start to run Car");
                    return;
                }
                list.add("Accelerate2");
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                String s = list.poll();
                model.addRow(new Object[] { s.substring(0, s.length() - 1) });

            }
        });
```

```
// Execute Accelerate Task
btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (!running) {
                        label_1.setText("Click start to run Car");
                        return;
                    }
                    accelerate();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

```
// Task that takes some time to get executed
public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            if (semaphore == 1) {
                semaphore--;
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                if (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    model.removeRow(0);
                }
                for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
                    label_1.setText("windows are closing .");
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                    label_1.setText("windows are closing ..");
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                    label_1.setText("windows are closing ...");
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                }
                label_1.setText("windows are closed");
                break;
            }
        }
        semaphore++;
    }
```